# Pandas dataframe plot for grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set of a tea export company and it includes total export and tea types and weight categories.

It looked like this

```
Date        Type    Weight    Quantity      Price
2016-01-01  black   bags      1734136.51    1131.30
2016-01-01  black   bulk      10722389.66   510.86
2016-01-01  black   4g_1kg    6817078.01    588.72
2016-01-01  black   1kg_3kg   86444.50      565.91
2016-01-01  black   3kg_5kg   1003986.73    552.39
```

Now that I have grouped the data with this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['YearMonth'] = df['Date'].map(lambda date: 100*date.year + date.month)

df = df.groupby(['YearMonth','Type', 'Weight']).agg({'Quantity':'sum'})
```

And the dataframe now looks like this

```
YearMonth   Type    Weight     Quantity
201601      black   1kg_3kg    86444.50
                    3kg_5kg    1003986.73
                    4g_1kg     6817078.01
                    5kg_10kg   2816810.33
                    bags       1734136.51
                    bulk       10722389.66
            green   3kg_5kg    12.00
                    4g_1kg     53014.95
                    5kg_10kg   1132.00
                    bags       41658.19
                    bulk       112400.00
            instant 4g_1kg     28.80
                    lt3kg      89486.40
201602      black   1kg_3kg    215539.60
```

Now I want to plot this in a graph. Date in x axis and type and weight in y axis. I tried the following code but it throws me an error.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
for key, df in df.groupby(['Quantity']):
    ax.plot(df['Type'], df['Weight'], label=key)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

The error I'm getting is

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[798], line 9
      7 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
      8 for key, df in df.groupby(['Quantity']):
----> 9     ax.plot(df['Type'], df['Weight'], label=key)
     11 ax.legend()
...
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Type'
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens and the best way to graph a plot with the data frame I have grouped above?

Comment: You could use `df.reset_index(level=1)` to convert the index to a normal dataframe column. Or, you could try to directly plot the dataframe via pandas: `df.plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multi-index after the groupby so there is no column label 'type'. You could select the group with index 'black' and yearmonth 201601 as follows and then plot as below; same could be done for different types using different symbols and marker colors.

```
df2 = df.loc[201601, 'black']
plt.scatter(df2.index, df2['Quantity'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is there any way I can select whole year at once. Let's say all 2016 months and 2017 and so on?

Comment: You could group on the `year, type and weight` and sum the quantity (so all months quantity aggregated) rather than using yearmonth. Lots of possible approaches to produce various plots as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about the kind of visualisation you're after, but here is what I think might be of use. I used [Seaborn's object interface](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) to render graphs, available from v0.12.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

sns.set_theme()
```

First, I prepared a sample dataset like this.

```py
np.random.seed(0)

weights = ["bulk", "bags", "5kg_10kg", "3kg_5kg", "lt3kg", "1kg_3kg", "4g_1kg"]
tea_types = ["black", "green", "instant"]

df_sample = (
    pd.DataFrame(data={
        "YearMonth": list(range(201601, 201611)) * 5,
        "Type": np.random.choice(tea_types, 50),
        "Weight": np.random.choice(weights, 50),
        "Quantity": np.random.random(50) * 1000
    })
    .astype({"Type": "category", "Weight": pd.CategoricalDtype(weights, ordered=True)})
    .groupby(["YearMonth", "Type", "Weight"], as_index=False).sum("Quantity")
    .sort_values(["YearMonth", "Type", "Weight"], ignore_index=True)
)
```

If we want to plot this with both `Weight` and `Type` in one graph, we can, for example, use a bar plot with dodge & stack at the same time.

```py
(
    so.Plot(df_sample, x="YearMonth", y="Quantity", color="Type", alpha="Weight")
    .add(so.Bars(width=0.7), so.Dodge(by=["color"]), so.Stack())
    .scale(
        x=so.Continuous().tick(every=1).label(like="{x:.0f}"),
        y=so.Continuous().label(like="{x:.0f}"),
        color=so.Nominal(values=["black", "green", "orange"], order=tea_types)
    )
    .layout(size=(10, 8))
)
```

[image]

However, it has a lot of information in one graph, it may look better if we use multiple graphs instead.

```py
(
    # Using `color` instead of `alpha` would be easier to distinguish different `Weight`s.
    so.Plot(df_sample, x="YearMonth", y="Quantity", alpha="Weight")
    .facet(row="Type")
    .add(so.Area(), so.Stack())
    .scale(
        x=so.Continuous().tick(every=1).label(like="{x:.0f}"),
        y=so.Continuous().label(like="{x:.0f}")
    )
    .layout(size=(10, 8))
)
```

[image]

Hope it helps!